# MS Sql not in table

Tags: sql

I am trying to wright a Microsoft sql statement that if on a piece of paper you draw two circles the intersect each other one labeled OH the other OLH I would get back all of OH not intersecting OLH. Here is what I got so far

```
select OE.pick_ticket_no, OLH.scanned
from p21_view_oe_pick_ticket as OE
LEFT JOIN jbi.dbo.order_logger_header as OLH On OE.pick_ticket_no = OLH.pickticket_no
  where NOT EXISTS ( 
    Select OLH.scanned
     FROM jbi.dbo.order_logger_header as OLH-- )      
     where OLH.scanned = 'N')
```

this returns all including the interception where OLH.Scanned is = 'Y'

Thanks in Advance
Donald S Bossen

Comment: Which dbms is this???

Comment: Is says  "MS SQL" in the title, so I guess SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see table `OH` on your original query.  But you can do this.

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1 OH
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table2 OHL
```

This will get everything that's in OH, but not in OHL.